# How to change colors in Montech Tower fans?

Tags: cpu, colors, fan

I built a gaming PC with tower from [Montech](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DN2HTC8)

How can I change colors for the tower fans? I can only get red and green lights? I know these are static colors but how can I get it to be rainbow colors?

Expected lights:

[image]

Actual image:

[image]

This is the image for the buttons, there is no LED button on this model compared to the Air X Model

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I get it to be rainbow colors?

Press the LED button:

> There are 6 lighting modes for the fans. Press the led button to
> switch every lighting mode.
>
> All the ARGB fans have already connected to the controller, providing
> easy access and control of the three fans through the LED button.
>
> Also, the ARGB fans can be fully customized and controlled by ARGB
> compatible mainboards (5V 3pin).
>
> - Change lighting mode : Press Led button for 1s
> - Motherboard control : Press Led button for 1.5s. (After the motherboard's software detected the fans)
> - Turn on / Turn off the light :  Press Led button for 3s

Source [Air X White](https://www.montechpc.com/en/products_detail.php?nid=153)

Comment: DavidPostill, there is no led button for the fighter model, I checked. There are two buttons on this the main button and restart compared to Air X White which has 3 buttons and the third one is LED button

Comment: DavidPostill, Appreciate your help. I added the image to the Post to show what i meant.